# How to enclose the excerpt in strong tags in a post

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to enclose the excerpt as written by an author (in the excerpt field or by using a `<!--more-->` tag) or generated by Wordpress itself, in `<strong>` tags in posts, but not in category listings. `the_content()` does not output the excerpt in a easily CSS-able tag, and `the_excerpt()` includes the [...] link, so I can't just call it and style it. `the_content()` also has the excerpt in it, so my experimentation with those methods have only produced double excerpts.

Is there a way to do this without hacking Wordpress itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rule of thumb here.**

If `the_excerpt()` has no values in the post, it will take part of `the_content()` as excerpt so you'll have duplication.

**Suggestion**

I would suggest using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) here to give you far more customisation than `the_excerpt()` allows. Saves time and have done so in many sites where you have had the same issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks like the solution for me, it seems more powerful than relying on Wordpress' internal functions :)

Comment: I'm glad this helps. Its not really the correct answer to your query but from experience I tend to avoid using `the_excerpt()` with my custom themes. It's just a little restrictive.

Advanced Custom Fields is a godsend for Wordpress.